# Как добавить иконки узлам Treeview?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, treeview

Нужно чтобы на каждом узле была одинаковая иконка.

Есть зачатки кода:

```
    private void images ()
    {
        ImageList imfolder = new ImageList();
        imfolder.Images.Add(Image.FromFile("dark_gray"));
        tree.ImageList = imfolder;
        tree.ImageIndex = 0;
        tree.SelectedImageIndex = 2;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно добавить иконку в самой разметке. Когда будете формировать DataContext, там ко всем узлам положите картинку. Далее просто биндитесь. Учтите, картинки в ресурсах хранятся в bitmap, а wpf надо imagesource. Для этого нужно еще конвертер.

```
 <TreeView 
                  VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"
                  VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Data}">
            <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Childs, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=OneWay}">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Image Source="{Binding Image, Converter={StaticResource ImgConverter}}"
                               Margin="0,0,5,0"
                               Width="16"
                               Height="16"
                               RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="NearestNeighbor"
                               RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=OneWay}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

Comment: Я еще новенький в c# и не пойму где этот блок текста который вы написали

Comment: вы используете технологию wpf?

Comment: Да в visual studio

Comment: там есть файлы с расширением .xaml.
Вот там пишется разметка

Comment: Для наглядности можете все упростить и вставить путь у иконки в Source 
<Image Source="путь к иконке"/>

Comment: Не могу найти файлы с таким расширением

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122491/discussion-between-cruz21-and-vikn).

Comment: Это не ответ, потому что используется другая технология. @vikn - почему вы приняли его?

Comment: Снял свой плюс: ответ был для wpf (и топикстартер изначально так указал, хотя по обсуждению в чате видно, что он не понимает разницы между wpf и winforms), так что формально ответ мимо вопроса. Вообще, можно доработать ответ, видно же по ссылкам в чате, что автор ответа разбирается.

Comment: Да я перепутал wpf с winforms